# How to mock both static methods and instances in jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock both a static method and instances of a class in a jest test with typescript and I am not sure how to get them both mocked. Here's a code example:

`record.ts`:

```
export default class Record {
  id: string;

  constructor(id : string) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  getId() : string {
    return this.id;
  }

  static getRecords() : Array<Record> {
    return [new Record('foo'), new Record('bar')]
  }
}
```

`reader.ts`:

```
import Record from './record';

export default class Reader {
  record: Record;
  constructor(record : Record) {
    this.record = record;
  }

  getRecordId() : string {
    return this.record.getId();
  }

  static getReaders() : Array<Reader> {
    return Record.getRecords().map((record) => new Reader(record))
  }
}
```

`reader.test.ts`:

```
import Reader from './reader'
import Record from './record'

jest.mock('./record');
const MockedRecord = Record as jest.Mocked<typeof Record>;
const mockRecord = new MockedRecord('bax');
MockedRecord.getRecords.mockImplementation(() => [mockRecord]);

describe('with getReaders', () => {
  it('returns the id of the associated records', () => {
    mockRecord.getId.mockImplementation(() => 'baz'); // This line fails because "Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '() => string'"
    expect(Reader.getReaders()[0].getRecordId()).toEqual('baz')
  })
})
```

The problem I'm finding here is that the `mockRecord` is not mocked, `mockRecord.getId` is just a normal function not a jest mock function.

Other things I've tried:

- Explicitly setting the mock as in `jest.mock('./record', () => {implementation})`, but then I run into typing trouble because the mock loses the static method that's in the signature of `Record`
- Using `import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';` and `const mockRecord = mocked(Record);` and then I run into `Property 'getId' does not exist on type 'MockedObject<typeof Record>'.`

Thank you!

Comment: Just a note, `Record` isn't a good name for an import because it interferes with TS own `Record` type.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I finally tried `const mockRecord = new MockedRecord('bax') as jest.Mocked<Record>;` and it worked!